# Como faço para que o Button só funcione se o EditText estiver preenchida?

Tags: android

Quero que só dê pra apertar no botão depois que todos os `EditText`'s estejam preenchidos

```
package com.example.marcosnogueira.appnote;


import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nome;
    private EditText nomlojcli;
    private EditText endereco;
    private EditText cpf;
    private EditText cnpj;
    private EditText tel;
    private Button cadastrar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
        nomlojcli = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nomlojcli);
        endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endereco);
        cpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpf)
        cnpj = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cnpj);
        tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tel);
        cadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        cadastrar.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mensagem = new AlertDialog.Builder(Principal.this);
                mensagem.setMessage("Cadastrado com Sucesso");
                mensagem.setNeutralButton("Ok",null);
                mensagem.show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua dúvida é o algoritmo? Você tem alguma ideia? Já tentou alguma coisa?

Comment: "só dê pra apertar" - refere-se a ficar inativo (`Enabled` a `false`) ou simplesmente não fazer nada quando se clica ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pensando aqui consegui encontrar dois meios de fazer isso.

1. O primeiro (que eu acho melhor por explicar o "erro", mas não exatamente o que você pediu) é deixar o botão clicável e ao clicar fazer uma `condição` verificando se todos os `EditText.length` (tamanho deles) são diferentes de zero, se sim, mostra o `AlertDialog`, se não, mostra um `Toast` falando que falta informações.

   ```
   eTNome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTNome);
   eTCidade = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTCidade);
   btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

   btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if(eTCidade.length() != 0 && eTNome.length() != 0){
               //Mensagem avisando "cadastro feito com sucesso"!
           } else {
               //Avisando pra colocar mais informações
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. A outra solução (que é o que você deseja) seria a cada mudança em um `EditText` verificar se todos estão preenchidos e se estiverem deixar o botão clicável, para isso podemos usar o `addTextChangedListener`, com ele você pode fazer ações antes, durante e depois que o texto for mudado, sobrescrevendo os métodos `beforeTextChanged`, `onTextChanged` e `afterTextChanged`, só usei o after, mas acho que em qualquer um serve, o código abaixo:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       Button btnSave;
       EditText eTNome;
       EditText eTCidade;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           eTNome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTNome);
           eTCidade = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eTCidade);
           btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
           btnSave.setEnabled(false);
           btnSave.setClickable(false);

           eTNome.addTextChangedListener(MudarTexto);
           eTCidade.addTextChangedListener(MudarTexto);
       }
       private TextWatcher MudarTexto = new TextWatcher(){
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           }

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
               AoMudarTexto();
           }
       };
       private void AoMudarTexto(){
           if(eTCidade.length() != 0 && eTNome.length() != 0) {
               btnSave.setEnabled(true);
               btnSave.setClickable(true);
           } else {
               btnSave.setEnabled(false);
               btnSave.setClickable(false);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Talvez fosse  preferível usar um único TextWatcher para todos os EditText's. Assim evitava repetição de código.

Comment: opa, não sabia que tinha como fazer isso, como eu poderia fazer? É que na verdade eu programo em C# com xamarin, aí não manjo tanto de Java, vou dar uma pesquisada e se encontrar algo eu edito o código para deixar melhor

Comment: Ah, já encontrei algo aqui, vou atualizar o código pra deixar melhor, obrigado pela dica ai!

Comment: Realmente, é melhor a solução 1. Mais simples e de melhor usabilidade. A solução 2 tem que ser combinada com algum tipo de indicador de qual é o problema. Não é nada legal ficar tentando clicar em um botão cinza e não conseguir porque não sabe o que está bloqueando ele.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida outra coisa que pode fazer é, quando ele estiver inacessível, mudar o texto para "Preencha as informações" ou algo do tipo, mas ainda assim prefiro o primeiro exemplo